# Filter for 2 criteria + 1 out 5 other criteria

Tags: r, dplyr

I have different patients that are characterised by IDs and I want to filter for those that have 2 lab criteria plus at least 1 out 5 other values. The names of the criteria are in one column, the results in another. I tried with `filter()` for and include the first required values with and, the other ones with or operator but I did not work.

Comment: Try: `filter(criteria1 & criteria2 & (one | two | three | four | five))`

Comment: Hard to reproduce without having example data, but you could make one or two new columns based on ifelse() a patient fulfills the criteria.